# How to find the ActionURL in a javascript __doPostBack

Tags: javascript, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm using VBA in excel to webscrape. I'm trying to pull down the URLs of links on a website.

Do a search on this website, with any of the checkboxes near the bottom checked:(http://www.fpi.co.za/YourFinancialPlanning/FindaFinancialPlanner/tabid/3255/Default.aspx)

You'll see there's a list of names here (advisers in south africa)

If you click on the name it will bring you to a new page. That being said, the method of URL change is actually through javascript `__doPostBack`, which means I can't simply `getelementsbyclassname().href`

I know that I can simply use VBA to click the link, and then store URL, but is there any way of obtaining that URL WITHOUT navigating to it?

This is the HREF I'm dealing with:

```
 javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr4953$Clients_Custom$ctl00$rg_Members$ctl00$ctl04$lnkName','')
```

Is there anything around `postBackOptions.ActionURL` or something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The website is an ASP.Net application. The JavaScript is auto-generated by .Net engine, and the function `__doPostBack()` is simply posting the arguments back to the server which is then redirecting to the other page. This means that the URL is on the server not in JavaScript, so there is no way for you to find it.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So is there no method in VBA of obtaining that URL without actually navigating there? Reason being that this website limits you to 9 "clicks" per session. Not great for webscraping!

Comment: No, like I said, the URL exists only on the server and never sent to the client until the redirect happens. Your VBA has no access to the server.

Comment: @Sapmess can't you force new sections?

Comment: @Sapmess, also, depending on what you need, it might be easy and cheap (with a binary search) to find the maximum FPI number for each year, assuming they are emitted sequentially (which does appear to be true).  Then you would have all existing profile URLs and, from that, you could build your own database or whatever it is that you need to do.