# Click on Href link through vba

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping, ie-automation

I am trying to create IEautomation through vba-excel for the following link.

URL: http://qpldocs.dla.mil/search/default.aspx

The code includes search for the string "QPL-631",and click on the corresponding java script link MIL-I-631D(6).When I inspected "MIL-I-631D(6)" link ,I found following source code of href tag

`<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('search_list$DG$ctl03$ctl00','')">MIL-I-631D(6)</a>`

So there are no click options for the `href` link and the address of manual clicking on `href` link is completely different than href address.So I am stuck here.I would like to add a code that clicks "MIL-I-631D(6)" and outputs the results.

I have tried the below code and so far and unable to proceed further.

`Private Sub IE_Autiomation()`

`Dim i As Long`

`Dim IE As Object`

`Dim objElement As Object`

`Dim objCollection As Object`

`Dim ae As HTMLLinkElement`

`Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

```
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://qpldocs.dla.mil/search/default.aspx"
Application.StatusBar = "Loading. Please wait..."
```

`Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

`Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."`
`IE.document.getElementById("Search_panel1_tbox").Value = "QPL-631"`
`IE.document.getElementById("Search_panel1_btn").Click`
 `Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop`

[image: 631 Link]

Comment: Are you legally allowed to scrape this website? Can't see anything saying you can't in the info they give....

Comment: It is an open source website for knowing the approved manufacturers.So I believe I am allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interim solution to write out to sheet as you are already hard coding the product code "QPL-631" you can just skip straight to using that in the URL string to return your results.

Note: I have pulled the table ID from that page:

```
html.getElementById("Lu_gov_DG")
```

You might want to explore if this is a common theme across products (I suspect yes). Will make life a lot easier. You could even do away with IE altogether and go for a faster XHR solution.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub IE_Automation()

    'References Internet Controls and HTML Object library

    Dim i As Long
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Dim product As String
    product = "QPL-631"

    Dim url As String

    url = "http://qpldocs.dla.mil/search/parts.aspx?qpl=1528&param=" & product & "&type=256"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE

        .Visible = True

        .navigate url                            '"http://qpldocs.dla.mil/search/default.aspx"

        Application.StatusBar = "Loading. Please wait..."

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set html = .Document

        Dim allRowOfData As Object

        Set allRowOfData = html.getElementById("Lu_gov_DG")

        Dim r As Long, c As Long

        Dim curHTMLRow As Object

        For r = 1 To allRowOfData.Rows.Length - 1

            Set curHTMLRow = allRowOfData.Rows(r)

            For c = 0 To curHTMLRow.Cells.Length - 1
                Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = curHTMLRow.Cells(c).innerText
            Next c

        Next r

        .Quit

    End With

    Application.StatusBar = False 'And tidy up our change to the status bar

End Sub
```

There is example with postback [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?20699-Javascript-_doPostback), which I will have a look at.

Reference:

1. [How to reset the Application.StatusBar](http://%20https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/567080-how-to-reset-the-application-statusbar.html)

Comment: Thanks.This will work only for QPL-631.What if I want to get the details of other QPL numbers? For instance QPL-38999,When I search for QPL-38999 and hit the `href` tag the url code would be `http://qpldocs.dla.mil/search/parts.aspx?qpl=1122&param=QPL-38999&type=256`.Just see the change of QPL number,it is now changed to **1122** in the address.So this is what I am interested to know.How is the `href` tag redirecting to unique QPL addresses and how to implement that into `vba` so that the code can search every QPL numbers.

Comment: Do you have a couple of other QPL numbers I can play around with please?

Comment: Here you have,QPL-AMS2644,QPL-6081,QPL-6529,QPL-6645,QPL-7808

Comment: So far this answer seems to imply that you can't access the re-direct URL as it is server side.....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377264/how-to-find-the-actionurl-in-a-javascript-dopostback

Answer (score 0):

You have several options available to you.  See below for a pretty comprehensive list of possibilities.

Try getting the collection of anchor tags, with:

```
GetElementsByTagName("a")
```

Then, iterate that collection using as much logic as you can to ensure you're clicking the right button.

For each l in ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

```
If l.ClassName = "hqt_button" Then
    l.Click
    Exit For
Next
```

If there are multiple anchors with the same classname, you could do:

```
If l.ClassName = "hqt_button" AND l.Href = ""javascript:void(0): onclick=HeaderBox.trySubmit()" Then
    l.Click
    Exit For
Next
```

Alternatively

If you are using IE9+ you could use the GetElementsByClassName method.

```
GetElementsByClassName("hqt_button")
```

[How do I use excel vba to click a link on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24638533/how-do-i-use-excel-vba-to-click-a-link-on-a-web-page)

Comment: i think, but I don't know, that the website is an ASP.Net application. and the function __doPostBack() is simply posting the arguments back to the server which is then redirecting to the other page hence why I haven't got a directly clickeable link. Was hoping @omegastripes or timwilliams might have seen this. But if you are familiar with this scenario as well, I am keen to see a solution. I included the link to a similar question in the comments.

Comment: @QHarr You are absolutely correct.@ryguy72 There are no `hqt button` arguments in the web page and hence the code posted by  won't serve the purpose.

Comment: @Neelesh thanks for clarifying. Is the OP question solveable? I would be keen to learn how to work with this. I am guessing you have to use postman or some such to see what is being passed back and forth?

Comment: Or use fiddler?

Comment: @QHarr Unfotunately No.I am not sure how to deal with those.